# What is a good git server frontend for self hosted git repositories

Tags: git, github, frontend

I am planning on deploying git for a project I am currently working on and was wondering if there are any free softwares that provide an easy to use web view of the git repository. I am primarily interested in using the front end to track changes, see diff information etc. There is a list of such front ends available [here](http://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Interfaces,_frontends,_and_tools#Web_Interface). Does anyone have any experience with any of these ? Which one would you suggest

An open source clone of github would do just fine actually :D but I know thats too much to ask .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used both gitweb and cgit in the past.  I like cgit better, but both should be fine.  FWIW, kernel.org exposes the Linux kernel trees through gitweb, and cgit is used by a lot of big open source projects (as listed on the wiki page that you reference), so I don't think you can go wrong with either :)

Comment: I decided on gitphp. Was a breeze to setup and all it needed was the .git folder.

Answer (score 4):

If it's solely for your personal use, you can use `git instaweb`. If you don't have lighttpd, you can run `git instaweb --httpd webrick`

See [gitready: Visualizing your repo](http://www.gitready.com/intermediate/2009/01/13/visualizing-your-repo.html)

If you're looking for a complete solution, gitorious is open source. It's not a github clone per se, but it provides pretty much the same functionality.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a team portal that supports git (as well as others) [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) is always a great option for collaboration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the viewer of redmine but not manage branch view.

You can use gitorious, but complicated to install it

Comment: Gitorious looks wonderful and also very complicated. As for the viewer, I am guessing I could also use Trac-Git for viewing the source tree.

Comment: exactly, there are some viewer possible. But not a lot to manage good view of branch